# What are the different licenses available in GitHub Android library?

Tags: android, github, licensing

Recently i added some code from GitHub repository for my android application.Though it's a Open Source Library, it shows different licenses like MIT,Apache etc... I am trying to get information about licenses. Can someone give notes about different licenses and how to use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns software licensing, rather than programming.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue. You may be able to get help at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) :D

Answer (score 9):

https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/ provides you way to use any of the available licence for projects.

There are so many types of software licences present.

> Microsoft Reciprocal License

A Microsoft open license and a free software license . Allows for distribution of derived code so long as the modified source files are included and retain the Ms-RL.
Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Code Project Open License (CPOL)

The main points subject to the terms of the License are:

Source Code and Executable Files can be used in commercial applications;
Source Code and Executable Files can be redistributed; and
Source Code can be modified to create derivative works.
No claim of suitability, guarantee, or any warranty whatsoever is provided. The software is provided "as-is".
Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Common Development and Distribution License (CDDL)

Based on the Mozilla Public License (MPL) that makes it more applicable for use outside the Mozilla Foundation.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: True
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)

Used by Microsoft. Compiled derived code can be distributed, for both commercial and non-commercial use. If the source code is to be redistributed then a complete copy of this license must be included in the redistribution.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Mozilla Public License 1.1 (MPL 1.1)

Used by Mozilla and Firefox, among others. The patent clauses are not acceptable to some.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: True
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Common Public License Version 1.0 (CPL)

Derived from the IBM Public License and influenced by the Mozilla Public License, and used by some Microsoft projects on SourceForge.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: True
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Eclipse Public License 1.0

A newer version of the Common Public License that is in some cases more acceptable to business.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: True
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The MIT License

A very old license with essentially no restrictions on the use of the code. It also provides very little in the way of protection for authors or users. It is the same as the BSD license without the 'no endorsement' clause.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The BSD License

A very old license with essentially no restrictions on the use of the code. It also provides very little in the way of protection for authors or users. It is the same as the MIT license except that it includes a clause preventing the use of the author's name for endorsement.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Apache License, Version 2.0

Slightly more restrictive (but still very open) version of the BSD or MIT license that adds patent clauses. Read carefully.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: True
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 License

A license that requires a link be visible on works that use this license. "Share alike" is what it sounds like, you can share this work as long as that work has a license similar to this one.

It is recommended that this license not be used for software.
Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: False
Is a viral licence: True

> The zlib/libpng License

A license with an emphasis on freedom of use and re-use, with a few restrictions.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> A Public Domain dedication

Not a license, but a dedication to the public domain. All rights are given up and anyone can do anything they wish with the code. Please note this is not a license and provides no guarantees for the user and no indemnities for the author.

Provides copyright protection: False
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: False

> The Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License

This license lets others distribute, remix, tweak, and build upon your work, even commercially, as long as they credit you for the original creation. It is recommended that this license not be used for software.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: False
Is a viral licence: True

> The Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License

A license that requires a link be visible on works that use this license. "Share alike" is what it sounds like; you can share this work as long as that work has a license similar to this one. It is recommended that this license not be used for software.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: False
Is a viral licence: True

> The Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivatives 3.0 Unported

A license which specifies that if you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material. It is recommended that this license not be used for software.
The Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivatives 3.0 Unported
Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: False
Is a viral licence: True

> The GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPLv3)

A derivative of the GPL that was intended to allow non-GPL code to work with, and call GPL code. The author of this license asks that you only use this license if you are licensing functionality already commonly available.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: True
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
Is a viral licence: True

> The GNU General Public License (GPLv3)

A common but misunderstood license. This allows developers to freely use the software as long as they use the same (or an even less restrictive) license for parts of the program that they wrote themselves. Viral in nature. Read carefully and make sure you understand the implications of using this license. Unacceptable to many.

You can write commercial software using software licensed with the GPL, but you cannot write proprietary software (meaning software for which the code is not freely available). You can sell GPL code, even if it's already being given away, or you can sell services attached to the code such as support contracts.

Any software written using GPL'd code must itself be licensed using the GPL (or less restrictive license) meaning it cannot be proprietary. This means that developers writing commercial software may not be able to use GPL code if they do not wish to provide the code.

One important note: The GPL doesn't require you to publish the source to the world. Only the recipient of the software needs to have the source. If you have a customer, write GPLed software for a specific purpose and only give the binary to this customer, then only this customer must have access to the source code, not everybody and not the public; just the recipient of the (binary) code. This is in full agreement to the GPL. The main advantage is to play with open cards and not create a "blackmail" situation.

Provides copyright protection: True
Can be used in commercial applications: True
Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: True
Provides an explicit patent license: False
Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: False
Is a viral licence: True

Comment: Nice summary but one major clarification re GPL : GPL prevents you from imposing limits on what the recipient can do with the source, except for removing the license. So in practice, GPL'd code in your commercial application implies you have to treat your code base as public, ie. not include intellectual property (data, algorithms, diagrams etc) that you want to hide from competiton.